# Populating a Form Using Promises or Async/Await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to populate a form using JavaScript promises or async/await (or similar) but just can't seem to get it. I tried `.then` and `Promise.all` with the same result: if one of the "get" functions takes longer than the getPunchlistItem function, the actual value is overwritten.

```
var myFSEs = [];
var myTypes = [];
var myPeople = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
  getFSEs("itemFSE", "Select FSE...")
    .then(getPersons("itemResponsible", "Select Person..."))
    .then(getTypes("itemType", "Select Type..."))
    .then(getPunchlistItem(myPLItemID));
 //or
  Promise.all([getFSEs("itemFSE", "Select FSE..."), getPersons("itemResponsible", "Select Person..."), getTypes("itemType", "Select Type...")]).then(function () {
    getPunchlistItem(myPLItemID);
  });
});
```

My async functions look like:

```
async function getFSEs(el, allText, filter) {
   getJson(myURL + "PunchlistTracking/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('FSEs')/items", function (data) {
   myFSEs = data.d.results.map(FSE => [`${FSE.Id}`, `${FSE.Title}`, `${FSE.FSEName}`]);
   var output = `<option value='0' selected='selected'>${allText}</option>`;

    for (var i = 0; i < myFSEs.length; i++) {
        if (`${myFSEs[i][3]}` == filter || !filter) {
            output += `<option value='${myFSEs[i][0]}'>${myFSEs[i][1]} ${myFSEs[i][2]}</option>`;
        }
    };

    $(`#${el}`).html(output);
    }, logError);

    return myFSEs;
}

function getJson(endpointUrl, success, failure) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    url: endpointUrl,
    success: success,
    failure: failure
  });
}   //  getJson
```

[image: Form Population Issue]

What am I missing?

Comment: `async` exists to enable `await` in a function body. `async` without `await` usually indicates a programming error (with a few arguably useful exceptions). Also, neither approach, direct use of promises or `async`/`await` would involve passing a callback to `getJson`.

Comment: Thanks Aluan, could you provide some details? Should it be 'await getJson(...'?

Comment: What is `getJson` in your question? If it returns a Thennable, such as a Promise, you can `await` it directly, otherwise, you will need to wrap it.

Comment: I added `getJson` above. It is an ajax call, which is thennable I understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
var myFSEs = [];
var myTypes = [];
var myPeople = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    (async () => {
        await getFSEs("FSEs", "All FSEs");
        await getPersons("Persons", "All Personnel");
        await getTypes("itemType", "Select Type...");
        getPunchlistItem(myPLItemID);
    })()    //  async
});
```

where my "get" functions look like:

```
function getFSEs(el, allText, filter) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        getJson(myURL + "PunchlistTracking/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('FSEs')/items", function (data) {
            myFSEs = data.d.results.map(FSE => [`${FSE.Id}`, `${FSE.Title}`, `${FSE.FSEName}`]);
            var output = `<option value='0' selected='selected'>${allText}</option>`;

            for (var i = 0; i < myFSEs.length; i++) {
                if (`${myFSEs[i][3]}` == filter || !filter) {
                    output += `<option value='${myFSEs[i][0]}'>${myFSEs[i][1]} ${myFSEs[i][2]}</option>`;
                }
            };

            $(`#${el}`).html(output);
            resolve();

        }, logError);
    });
}
```

Comment: If you add a bit of explanation of what you ended up doing and why it works, that would be very helpful for future people reading this post!